# Lotusscript : Can I detect picture in rich text field?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a problem with my program that because my user like to attach the screen-capture picture into rich-text field

ex.

[image]

And my program can not detect them...

[image]

Can everyone share your idea ?...

thank you.

Comment: Export to dxl and parse it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `NotesRichTextNavigator` for your rich text field. Obtain the navigator via

```
Set notesRichTextNavigator  =  notesRichTextItem .CreateNavigator
```

Then for `notesRichTextNavigator` object, use `FindFirstElement` and `FindNextElement` calls to examine rich text field contents for particular element types.

Check the navigator class API reference here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESRICHTEXTNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html

---

**UPDATE**

I have checked some things with Notes Designer and I have to say the following.

Navigator approach described above is not suitable to check for pictures pasted to the rich text field. Standard notes functionality does not allow to check whether a rich-text item contains an embedded picture object.

Neither `notesDocument.HasEmbedded` nor `richtextItem.EmbeddedObjects` show contained embedded pictures.

But described way is possible to control file attachments, ole objects and document links according to the API specification.

Please note, if you are working with a notesDocument which was not saved, i.e it is a `new document`, you should call `notesUIDocument.Refresh(true)` to pass rich text item from front-end UI document to back-end notesDocument. Otherwise `getFirstItem(richTextFieldName)` will return `Nothing`.

Comment: sorry, i stuck in notesRichTextNavigator cannot get a file same this topic https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28140436/Lotusscript-extract-picture-from-lotus-form.html

if I remark check "doc.HasEmbedded" , rnav will also blank ..

Comment: Please check my update. Regarding your question in comment - I don't understand what went wrong in your case. Please clarify.

Comment: Was there any updates on this? This thread doesn't appear to have any real working solution.